# Whenever gem is not sending an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, whenever

I want to resend an activation email to users if they do not activate it in 48 hours. I used whenever gem but it is not sending the email. even if action mailer works fine and sends an email when a user signs up
 **schedule.rb**

```
 set :environment, :development
      every 1.minutes do
        runner "user.resend_account_activation"
    end
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
def resend_account_activation
    @user = User.where('activated = ?',false && 'activated_at < ?',48.hours.ago)

    mail to: @user.email, subject: "You forgot to activate"
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
 def resend_account_activation
      # @outdated_users = User.where('activated_at < ?',30.seconds.ago)
      UserMailer.resend_account_activation.deliver_now!

  end
```

**In my cmd**

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: store
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/c/Sites/testApp && bin/rails runner -e production '\''user.resend_account_activation'\'''

# End Whenever generated tasks for: store
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should not be `user.resend_account_activation`

It will be something like this

`user.rb`

```
def self.resend_account_activation_to_users
  User.where('activated = ? AND activated_at < ?', false ,48.hours.ago).each do |user|
    UserMailer.resend_account_activation(user.id).deliver_now!
  end
end
```

Note: I have changed the 48 hrs query. pls check before execution

`user_mailer.rb`

```
def resend_account_activation(user_id)
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  mail to: @user.email, subject: "You forgot to activate"
end
```

`runner "User.resend_account_activation" # Note: changed user => User`

Comment: I am not sure about this query. `User.where('activated = ?',false && 'activated_at < ?',48.hours.ago)`